# ULabel resizing without reason when using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UIlabel` with dynamic height, it should have the height of the containing text (that's why I have set the vertical hugging priority to high).

However, the `UILabel` gets higher when the text gets wider, ignoring that the text did not even reach the second line. I can even reproduce it in IB.

With short text:

[image]

With large text:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this problem? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused because `Preferred Width` was set to a width due to the warnings in iOS7:

> Automatic Preferrred Max Layout width is not available on iOS versions
>   prior to 8.0

I solved the bug by setting `Preferred Width` to 0.